# Android Kotlin Protected property exposes its private type ExpiresLayout

Tags: android, kotlin

I converted my Java Activity class using Android Studio Kotlin plugin. `Android Studio > Code > 'Converting Java code to Kotlin'`

I am getting this error.

> Error:(109, 19) 'protected (in Fragment)' property exposes
>   its 'private' type ExpiresLayout

Code

```
protected val mExpiresLayout = ExpiresLayout.NORMAL
```

Any Idea? Thanks

Comment: Make it private, or if you need `ExpiresLayout` to be accessible outside your class then make that protected

Comment: @quiro please make your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: answer added @KirillRakhman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either make it private, or if you need ExpiresLayout to be accessible outside your class then make that protected.

What's happening is that by declaring the `mExpiresLayout` value as `protected` you're exposing a private class outside its domain (it's visible to subclass and other classes in the same package) which is illegal.